# Windows 7 Home Premium reinstallation with another language

Tags: windows, laptop, installation, license-key, product-key

I bought a laptop with preinstalled Windows 7 Home Premium.

After the problem with installation of the Ubuntu, I reinstalled Windows from the disk that was in the box with laptop. The problem is the it has another language (not English). Thus I would like to install English version of Windows (Home Premium as initial).

May I use the same product key (written on the laptop) for installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, only windows 7 **ultimate** has *multiple language packs*, the key you used for **home premium** is linked to that *specific language*

You could try installing ultimate after you pick your language pack with the premium key, but there is no guarantee that would work. Or you could put in ultimate, not activate it and when it asks for activation put in the premium key, again no guarantees.

Additionally, you could obtain the [language pack](http://download.windowsupdate.com/msdownload/update/software/updt/2009/08/windows6.1-kb972813-x86-en-us_22ee3397a02372681b375ddabf6ffa33662fd500.exe) included in ultimate that has been completely untested by me.

Comment: Just to clarify, when I first time started the windows it allowed me to choose the language, but at the disk that I got with laptop it was only the other one. Also, I didn't entered this key during the installation.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean

Comment: I mean that I didn't entered this code anywhere and at the first start of the laptop I choosed English language from two languages in list. Does it change anything?

Comment: It's unlikely using the key will revert your current installation to a different language, so yes, activate with the key. Worst that happens is it won't activate and you call Microsoft to get it activated.

Comment: Got an answer from microsoft. They say that I can use this key for this computer but possibly I'll need to activate it by phone as you said. Any way, thank you for answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may create your own recovery discs using the Dell DataSafe Local Backup application if you are still able to boot to Windows. You may visit the link below to know more about creating the recovery discs:

http://support.dell.com/support/topics/g…

If the system is not booting up, however, the recovery partition is still there, you may perform a Dell PC Restore to take the system back to factory settings. Detailed information on PC Restore is available on this link:

http://support.dell.com/support/topics/g…

If the recovery partition is no longer there, then you would need the discs to reinstall the Windows.